# Is there a standard way to create homebrew monsters' stat blocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, homebrew, monster-design

Let's suppose that I want to create a homebrew monster with some equipment, like magic items such as necklaces, potions, etc. **My question is: is there a standard way to add equipment to the monster stat block?** Thank you.

---

As an example, let's consider the following homebrew:

[image]

**Armor Class** 17 (studded leather)

**Hit Points**  65 (10d8 + 20)

**Speed**       30 ft.

---

| STR | DEX | CON | INT | WIS | CHA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 (+3) | 20 (+5) | 15 (+2) | 11 (+0) | 16 (+3) | 10 (+0) |

---

**Saving Throws**        Con +5, Wis +6

**Skills**               Athletics +6, Perception +6, Stealth +8

**Senses**               passive Perception 16

**Languages**            any one language (usually Common)

**Challenge**            5 (1,800 XP)

---

***Pack Tactics.*** The elite soldier has advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of the elite soldier's allies is within 5 ft. of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.

***Gas Mask.*** While wearing a gas mask, the wearer can breathe normally in any environment, and he has advantage on saving throws made against harmful gases and vapors (such as cloudkill and stinking cloud effects, inhaled poisons, and the breath weapons of some dragons). A gas mask is good for 24 hours of use. After that time, its filter must be replaced in order for it to provide a benefit. The wearer can replace the filter with a Use an Object action.

#### Actions

***Multiattack.*** The elite soldier makes three ranged attacks.

***Hunting Rifle.*** *Ranged Weapon Attack:* +8 to hit, range 80/240 ft, one target. *Hit*: 16 (2d10 + 5) piercing damage.

***Fragmentation Grenade.*** As an action, the elite soldier can throw a grenade at a point up to 60 ft. away. Each creature within 20 ft. of an exploding fragmentation grenade must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw, taking 17 (5d6) piercing damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

---

I gave him a gas mask, and I specified this in the features section of the stat block. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The “Special Traits” section as described in the intro to the *Monster Manual*.

A monster’s stat block is explained in the intro to the *Monster Manual*, and your gas mask trait is a “Special Trait”:

> Special traits (which appear after a monster’s challenge rating but before any actions or reactions) are characteristics that are likely to be relevant in a combat encounter and that require some explanation.

The “Statistics” section of the introduction gives the full breakdown of a stat block (pp. 6-11, Special Traits on p. 10).

Additionally, chapter 9 of the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* has detailed guidance for building homebrew creatures (pp. 273-283).

Comment: Thank you. If I would give some healing potions to the creature, should I treat them as a special trait?

Comment: @Leonardo You could do it there, specifying that it costs an action and has X uses, or you could put it in the Actions section and specify the uses.

Comment: If they are used as an action, I'd list them in the Actions section. It's so that when a DM is running an encounter with the statblock and they're thinking up what your monster is going to do as their next move, you have all that info concisely in one spot. Putting it in as a trait risks the DM forgetting it's even an option in the heat of the fight. In short, traits tell you "what's special about this monster that might come into play at any time" and actions tell you "what I might have it do on its turn".